# What are the special features of machine learning source code that different from other kinds of programs?

Tags: machine-learning

I just want to know in detail about this question, in view of software engineering. What are the special features of machine learning source code that different from other kinds of program? I only know that, ML programs have to manipulate many complex data sets, and perform many mathematical computations. So, such programs often difficult to debug, or to analyze the execution?

Comment: Maybe a bit more specific. Suggested is to open the question with either samples of what you read from others (if they are inconsistent) or a tried summay (if they are). Also a title of the question might be more a summary then a copy of two thirds of the question text. It helps motivate those to take the time to answer, when they notice, someone took the time to ask ;-)

Comment: It solves Machine Learning problems.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just give some features I know, and want to know more :D

Answer (score 0):

I want to find some ideas of software verification that apply to ML programs, so I want to know the special features